# How to make String array into Int Array Kotlin Android

Tags: android, arrays, function, kotlin, calculator

I'm very new to Kotlin and Android. I have created an array that accepts input from EditText of 10 values separated by commas, however It is a String array and I need a Int array. Any Help would be very Appreciated. Below is my code:

```
private fun array() {
        val ed = findViewById<View>(R.id.et_addNum) as EditText
        var text = ed.text.toString()
        val array: List<String> = text.split(",")
        
        for (element in array) {
            Log.e("elements", element)

            storednumber.setText(array.toString())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely sure your `String`s are correct numbers you can use mapping like this:

```
val stringList: List<String> = listOf("1", "2", "3")
val intList: List<Int> = stringList.map { it.toInt() }
```

or like this if want to avoid throwing `NumberFormatException`:

```
val stringList: List<String> = listOf("1", "2", "3")
val intList: List<Int> = stringList.map { it.toIntOrNull() ?: 0 }
```